# Unable to update GitHub CLI on Windows to version 1.5.0 using Scoop

Tags: powershell, github-cli, scoop-installer

Earlier today I have installed GitHub CLI package on my windows 10 machine, while I was writing an article about how to install and config GitHub CLI on windows. for that purpose I have installed [Scoop](https://scoop.sh/) and use it with running `scoop install gh` to install the CLI. two hours later GitHub released CLI version of [1.5.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v1.5.0). I am now trying to updating my gh version with scoop running `scoop update gh` but the output in the Windows PowerShell says it's already updated and refers to version 1.4.0 as the last version.

```
Updating 'main' bucket...
Checking repo... ok
The main bucket was added successfully.
Scoop was updated successfully!
gh: 1.4.0 (latest version)
Latest versions for all apps are installed! For more information try 'scoop status'
```

I appreciate any insight on how I might use scoop to update a package GitHub CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried that out the next day, and it worked.
The output massages from running `scoop gh update` itself provide the answer that is:

> scoop run it's sniffing process over a large number of libraries, and
> that's the reason for the delay before it update it's references. It refers to period of time between event occurrence and data availability, the **Data Freshness** rate could be daily or **Time Zone** related for the scoop platform.

I am providing the output here:

```
 scoop update gh                                                                                       Updating Scoop...                                                                                                       Updating 'main' bucket...
 * 021a07f95 vim-nightly: Update to version 8.2.2389                     4 hours ago
 * 8460e4a56 gh: Update to version 1.5.0                                 4 hours ago
 * 3d17708f1 doctl: Update to version 1.55.0                             4 hours ago
 * 0129735ec azure-functions-core-tools: Update to version 3.0.3245      4 hours ago
 * c796dbc39 argocd: Update to version 1.8.3                             4 hours ago
 * 3784173a5 pulumi: Update to version 2.18.1                            9 hours ago
 * 1e550f204 aws: Update to version 2.1.21                               11 hours ago
 * 41d6beb5e heroku-cli: Update to version 7.47.10                       12 hours ago
Scoop was updated successfully!
gh: 1.4.0 -> 1.5.0
Updating one outdated app:
Updating 'gh' (1.4.0 -> 1.5.0)
Downloading new version
gh_1.5.0_windows_amd64.zip (5.6 MB) [=========================================================================] 100%
Checking hash of gh_1.5.0_windows_amd64.zip ... ok.
Uninstalling 'gh' (1.4.0)
Removing shim for 'gh'.
Unlinking ~\scoop\apps\gh\current
Installing 'gh' (1.5.0) [64bit]
Loading gh_1.5.0_windows_amd64.zip from cache
Extracting gh_1.5.0_windows_amd64.zip ... done.
Linking ~\scoop\apps\gh\current => ~\scoop\apps\gh\1.5.0
Creating shim for 'gh'.
'gh' (1.5.0) was installed successfully!
```